# Change all object pointing to an instance

Tags: java, file

Lets say i have an interface `Player` and two classes that derives from it: `LoadedPlayer` and `UnloadedPlayer`, `LoadedPlayer` is used when the computer needs it and it's saved in ram memory, `UnloadedPlayer` is used when the computer doesn't need it and it's saved to a file, infact the instance only contains a reference to the file.
how can i switch between loaded and unloaded without creating an ugly box class and incapsulating them?

Comment: Just a note, it's more accurate to say two classes that *implement* an interface rather than *derive* which is a term more used for inheritance, i.e. the `extends` relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by keeping a list of all the places the reference is used.  This ways you change change all the references as required, however this is somewhat error prone.

Another approach is to use a persisted map and reference the player via a key e.g. a unique name. As the map is persisted you don't need to know when it is written disk, but you need to make sure the Map is updated when you change the data for the player.

Examples of such a Map is Chronicle Map, MapDB, Hazelcast, Terracotta, Grid Gain, Coherence, too many to mention.

If you have you own `Reference` type you can simplify the proxy.  You can do thing like

```
Reference<Player> ref = ..
Player player = ref.get();
```

if you need to know when the player is being used you can do this.

```
ref.with(player -> doSomething(player));
```

This way you can hold.lock the player while being used and release it when done.

Comment: So the cleanest method is to create a box class, isn't it?

Comment: @SnowyCoder A delegating proxy class would be much simpler. Another approach is to use a `Reference` object which has a `get()` to explicitly get the Player.  This would simplify the code, esp if you have lots of methods.